# calling a server side function with parameter inline C#

Tags: c#

can anyone help me with this :

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rep_Categories" runat="server" >
       <ItemTemplate>
      <li><a href='<%#WriteUrl("<%#Eval("PARTNER_CATEGORY_NAME")%>"," <%#Eval("PARTNER_CATEGORY_ID")%>") %>'  ><%# Eval("PARTNER_CATEGORY_NAME") %>  </a></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

server side :

```
 public string WriteUrl(string PartnerName, string CategoryID)
{
    string url=Page.GetRouteUrl("Category ID", new { PartnerName = PartnerName } + "," + new { CatID = CategoryID });
    return url;
}
```

i know that my syntax above is incorrect but i cldn't manage to find a way to fix it can anyone tell me how can i fix my problem ?

Comment: Try making the parameters `object`

Comment: what do you mean i didn't understand

Comment: `public string WriteUrl(object PartnerName, object CategoryID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rearrange the quotes combination

```
<a href='<%# WriteUrl(Eval("PARTNER_CATEGORY_NAME").ToString(), Eval("PARTNER_CATEGORY_ID").ToString()) %>'     </a></li>
```

Comment: i did that it gave me an error : Error 6 Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line C:\Users\balamdin\Desktop\viva\Default.aspx 92

Comment: You are welcome, what was reason for error and what you have found?

Comment: <a href='<%#WriteUrl(Eval("PARTNER_CATEGORY_NAME").ToString(),Eval("PARTNER_CATEGORY_ID").ToString())%>'   >